# assign value multiple times array, python

Tags: python

I have a list of elements in Python and need to assign a number to the entire list. In `R`, I could simply do the assignment and `R` would `rep` that number the necessary number of times. In Python, is the easiest thing to do a list comprehension?

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
#want to assign 0 to every element, would like to do x[:] = 0 but this causes an error
x[:] = [0 for i in range(len(x))] #pretty long for such a simple operation
```

Comment: What's the difference between "assigning 0 to the entire list" and "making a new list of 0s the same length"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a comprehension such as `[0 for _ in x]` is the way to go (no need for `range(len(...` if you're not doing anything with the values). R's syntax places heavy emphasis on vectors, while Python has a preference for explicit instructions in this sort of case.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
x = [0] * len(x)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> x[:] = [0]*len(x)
>>> x
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: using the multiplication operator can be dangerous on mutable objects. Probably worth mentioning...